# Animation and loading like around me application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I would like to implement the same type of loading functionality and animation  as this application: https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/aroundme/id290051590?mt=8

I have been trying to find information on how to do this but can't quite seem to find any good resources.

How can I accomplish this? Even just an idea of what to properly google search will be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1):

It's called ripple effect 
There is demo you can find from below link

https://github.com/bharathlalgudinatarajan/LNBRippleEffect

Other option is you can find/implement last colum 3rd effect from below link.

https://github.com/gontovnik/DGActivityIndicatorView

Comment: But how to implement the animation effect when the user tap on tableview cell and image go to the next screen

Comment: I can't get you what exactly you want but might be you can find your solution from https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=ripple OR https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rippletableviewcontroller